# The Object you want to instantiate is null. Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem with my unity code and i can't get it why it doesn't work. I am kinda new to unity, just starting to learn it. I have 4 prefabs with different name in the project tree, and i want a prefab to spawn every second, but i want it to be randomized without using "if"'s, so i tried to save the prefabs names in an array and then Instantiate the GameObject that has the same name with the value of the array. When i run my script in Unity it says that the object i want to instantiate is null, i tried to find an answer on the web, but i found nothing. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawnnoif : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cub;
    public GameObject capsula;
    public GameObject cilindru;
    public GameObject sfera;
    public int x;
    public GameObject paleta;
    public float delta;
    public string[] a = { "cub", "capsula", "cilindru", "sfera" };

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), 1, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
        x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3);
        Instantiate(GameObject.Find(a[x]), position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), 1, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
            x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3);
            Instantiate(GameObject.Find(a[x]), position, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `GameObject.Find(a[x])` returns something?

Comment: I moved now the GameObjects into the scene, looks like this was a problem, but still, it only generates cubes, no other object is generated

Comment: Are all the objects with the correct tag name?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra `Find` has nothing to do with tags but only with the object names

Answer (score 1):

Please **don't** use [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) for this! It is extremely expensive! And unreliable!

> This function only returns active `GameObjects`. If no GameObject with name can be found, **`null` is returned**.

Especially since it looks like you want to use this for prefabs that only exist in the Assets and not in the Scene this will always return `null` as it only finds objects from the Scene.

---

Rather use an array like

```
public GameObject[] Prefabs;
```

reference your objects here and simply do

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
Instantiate(Prefabs[Random.Range(0, Prefabs.Length)], position, Quaternion.identity);
```

---

To your `IEnuemrator` ... well, you never start this as a Coroutine so it is simply never running.

You can do it directly in `Start` using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawn());
}

private IEnumerator Spawn()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
        Instantiate(Prefabs[Random.Range(0, Prefabs.Length)], position, Quaternion.identity);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
}
```

actually you could even directly use

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
        Instantiate(Prefabs[Random.Range(0, Prefabs.Length)], position, Quaternion.identity);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
}
```

If `Start` is declared as `IEnumerator` Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine.

---

Or in such a simple case you could even use [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) like

```
private void Start()
{
    // second parameter is the initial delay
    // last parameter the repeat interval
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(Spawn), 0, 1.0f);
}

private void Spawn()
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
    Instantiate(Prefabs[Random.Range(0, Prefabs.Length)], position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: @schneebuzz **No!** as said the last parameter of [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) for `int` is **exclusive** and therefore ever reached. You do **not** pass in `Length - 1` : `Note max is exclusive. Random.Range(0, 10) can return a value between 0 and 9.`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! Now i still have problem with the IEnumerator, it's not spawning any other gameobjets, just the first one that is called in Start()

Comment: @MorarMihai Well ... you never start that Coroutine ^^ See Update

Comment: Does this work on Android ?

Comment: @AmirSafari why should it not? This only includes very basic Unity API which is platform agnostic

Comment: @derHugo Sorry I commented on the wrong question but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of GameObjects (the prefabs) and assign them in the editor. Then you can assign as many prefabs as you want in the Inspector and spawn them randomly:

```
public class Spawnnoif : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] prefabs;

    public int x;
    public GameObject paleta;
    public float delta;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1.88f, 2.1f), 1, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-7.81f, -3.1f));
        x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length);
        Instantiate(prefabs[x], position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @derHugo Yes you were slightly faster I guess :) You are right, I just suggested an edit to your post but I am actually wrong. If only `range` implementations were the same in different technologies ;)

Comment: You need to use the same code in the `Spawn()` method. Then you also need to start the Coroutine inside `Start` using [`StartCoroutine(Spawn())`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Comment: That worked! Sorry for stupid questions, but i am kinda new, started like a week ago with unity, i still find it hard to understand how and where i should call the functions